# Schema validation errors while parsing config.xml - Invalid xsi:type qname: error: failed to load java type corresponding to t=ashland-authenticatorT

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

### Below is the error, i have while starting the weblogic Admin server after creating the domain from the domain template builder.jar file,

<Jul 20, 2021 9:44:51 AM EDT>    <Schema validation errors while parsing /oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/config/config.xml<43:7> - Invalid xsi:type qname: 'ext:ashland-authenticatorType' in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<Jul 20, 2021 9:44:51 AM EDT>    <Schema validation errors while parsing /oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/config/config.xml - /oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/:43:7: error: failed to load java type corresponding to t=ashland-authenticatorType@http://www.ashland.com/weblogic12c/security/extension.>
<Jul 20, 2021 9:44:51 AM EDT>    <Schema validation errors while parsing /oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/config/config.xml<53:7> - Invalid xsi:type qname: 'ext:ashland-authorizerType' in element realm@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain.>
<Jul 20, 2021 9:44:51 AM EDT>    <Schema validation errors while parsing /oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/config/config.xml - /oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/:53:7: error: failed to load java type corresponding to t=ashland-authorizerType@http://www.ashland.com/weblogic12c/security/extension.>

Comment: Ok, did you double-check spelling, syntax, correct values of your file `/oracle/user_projects/domains/awt-dv/config/config.xml` ?

Comment: It appears that your domain is using a custom seurity provider "ashland-authorizer" but required java files are missing from the classpath. Add them and try to start your server

Comment: I have checked the config.xml and the values are correct and also could you please suggest me what are java files missing so that i can add it.